# What are special spells?

Tags: nethack

http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Spellcasting

> This chance of failure is affected by intelligence (or wisdom), experience level, skill level, innate magical ability of the role, armour: especially metal but also shields and robes, whether it is an emergency spell or your **special spell**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A special spell has a higher rate of successful casting. Each role has one special spell. These are listed in this [table](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Special_spell#Role_penalties).

Comment: Thank you! How does one figure this out though? I've never seen it mentioned on the wiki.

Comment: @I take, Seems it got lost in the transition from the old wikia to the new wiki. http://nethack.wikia.com/wiki/Spellcasting#Equipment_and_role_penalties